# I want to get header response of a url using a proxy with a username, password, host and port?

Tags: linux, proxy, authentication, http

I want to get header response of a URL by using proxy username, password, host and port? is there any Linux command to get the same response?

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should give you what you want....

```
export http_proxy="http://myhttpdproxy.com:3128"  

wget -q --server-response -O /dev/null  --proxy-user=USER  \
--proxy-password=PASS  http://www.google.co.uk/
```

(if I have understood the question correctly) Its likely possible to produce some similar result with either curl or perl with LWP module, if you are on a distro with no wget...)

Answer (score 1):

The `curl` version of Tom H's answer is:

```
curl -I -U user:password -x http://myhttpdproxy.com:3128 http://www.google.co.uk/
```

Both `curl` and `wget` will also honour environment variables with the username and password such as:

```
export http_proxy="http://user:password@myhttpdproxy.com:3128"
```

Feel free to wrap the password in quotes if it contains characters that bash will interpret such as `!, *, \, <, >, |, ~` or several others.

Note that using the password on the command line like that will cause it to end up in your bash history and usually be available in a process listing while the command is running.  There doesn't seem to be an option to read the password from a file but putting the whole command in a bash script will at least keep the password out of your bash history.  Putting the environment variable in your `~/.bash_profile` would seem to be the best method.